# How to commit Kafka offset manually using Spring Cloud Stream reactive functions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to commit offset manually in Kafka consumer by using java functions(Consumer) in Spring cloud stream, but the offset is getting committed after java function executed successfully.

```
enable.auto.commit: false
ack-mode: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, String>> process() {
 
     return stream -> stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
            
            logger.info("Key: " + key + " Value: " + key);

     }

}
```

Can some one help to provide the correct configuration for manual commit offset in Spring cloud kafka consumer function

Comment: Kafka Streams cannot control manual commits

Comment: I'm writing a program by using Kafka Stream and I want to process records as a batch and commit the last offset manually. In this way I can avoid commit offset in case any errors during process.  Is there any way to have manual commit in Spring Cloud Stream

Comment: Kafka Streams commits automatically. It cannot be controlled, whether using Spring, or not. You can add ExceptionHandlers in your StreamsConfig

Comment: Is there any way that I can have to commit offset manually Using Spring boot and Kafka. My challenge is I have to process the batch of records and then commit the last offset manually so that if there is any issue during the process we can recover all the transactions. If Kafka commits offset automatically for every record, then I may lose transactions while I'm processing as a batch of records

Comment: Yes, you'd not use Kafka Streams to be able to control offsets manually for record batches... Refer the Spring Kafka documentation for examples (not Cloud Streams)

Comment: Workaround: I tried to increase commit.interval.ms to 2 hours from 30 seconds and processed multiple records(say 100) from Kafka and then used ProcesserContext#commit() method to commit offset manually. In this way I'm able to commit offset manually and it is working fine.

Is this the correct way to increase commit.interval.ms when enable.auto.commit is false?

Comment: Sounds fine, but won't guarantee you've processed X amount of records.